# Does SEManage fcontext require restorecon?

Tags: linux, selinux

I'm trying to write policies for selinux and I'm figuring something out.
If i run this command:

semanage fcontext -a -t /home/Ben '/websites(/.*)?'

Is there a need to run restorecon? Also what exactly does restorecon do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [restorecon not setting fcontext created using semanage](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/562536/restorecon-not-setting-fcontext-created-using-semanage)